# openCPU: Strange Error "Versuch eine Nicht-Funktion anzuwenden" in single-Server development mode

Tags: r, web-applications, opencpu

I'm stuck in the development of a R-Application using openCPU by a strange behavior of the single server development mode.
My R package let say its called 'myPkgName' contains several functions which are ment to be used as an interface to openCPU. 
One of them is called `ocpu_pat2list`.

1. When i try the funcion in plain R, it works properly.
2. When I start the testing modus by calling `opencpu::ocpu_start_app("myPkgName")` in R and use the test interface `http://localhost:5656/ocpu/test/`, the function is working properly.
3. But when I start my application and debug it's behaviour in the browser, the application crashes with the following error:

.

```
OpenCPU error HTTP 400
Versuch eine Nicht-Funktion anzuwenden

In call:
(function (x) 
x$.self$finalize())(<environment>)

opencpu-0.4.js:9:54
XML-Verarbeitungsfehler: Syntax-Fehler
Adresse: http://localhost:5656/ocpu/library/myPkgName/R/ocpu_pat2list/json
Zeile Nr. 1, Spalte 1:
```

Even more strange, so far the this error does not occure when I run the application on the real target Server. However in order to stay efficent I realy would like to get rid of this error or even understand what the Problem is at all.

Note:

- I installed the latest Version of openCPU.
- The call of the function is a 'POST' call providing one Parameter
- The error occurs also without `/json`

The function in question looks like this:

```
ocpu_pat2list <- function(patId){
  if(missing(patId)){
    stop("patId is missing")
  }
  if(is.character(patId)){
    patId <- as.numeric(patId)
  }
  pat <- PatRefClass(patId)
  pat$db_getPatInfo()
  pat$db_getPatData()
  ret <- pat$toList()
  return(ret)
}
```

I'm thankful for any idea.

Comment: Very hard to help you, since we can not exclude possible errors from your function call. maybe try expanding upon that and not only paste the error message?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What exactly do you want to know? The function is quite simple and returns a list object containing some infos. As I said the function works fine in R and even when i test it 'by hand'. But if it helps I'll will include the source of the function to the question.